# How to ng-show element on scroll when it is into view in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

That's my code and it doesn't work. What's wrong with it?

**HTML**

```
<i ng-show="whenIconsIntoView()" class="fa fa-mail"></i>
```

**JS**

```
app.controller('AboutCtrl', ['$scope', '$window', function($scope, $window){
    // some function to detect is scroll into user's view
    isScrolledIntoView = function(elem) {...}

    $window.onscroll = function() {
        $scope.whenIconsIntoView = function(){
            $scope.$apply(function() {
                return isScrolledIntoView('.icons');
            });     
        };
    };
}]);
```

Comment: does this function is inside ng-repeat?

Comment: No, what does it change?

Comment: Just FYI if `isScrolledIntoView()` returns a boolean, your scope function can just do `return isScrolledIntoView('.icons')` - the ternary operator is unnecessary

Comment: Have you checked that `isScrolledIntoView()` is actually working as expected? Just by using `console.log` inside the `$window.onscroll`

Comment: Yes, it works. And function returning correctly.

Comment: @Alliswell  could you please share you code of `isScrolledIntoView()` method

Comment: `isScrolledIntoView = function(elem) {
     var winViewTop = $(window).scrollTop();
     var winViewBottom = winViewTop + $(window).height();
     var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
     var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();
     return ((elemBottom >= winViewTop) && (elemTop <= winViewBottom));}'

Answer (score 0):

Give a try by more angular way code

```
app.controller('AboutCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope, $window) {
    // some function to detect is scroll into user's view
    isScrolledIntoView = function(elem) {...
    }

    $window[0].on('scroll', function() {
        $scope.whenIconsIntoView = function() {
            $scope.$apply(function() { //need to run digest cycle from events
                return (isScrolledIntoView('.icons')) ? true : false;
            });
        };
    });
}]);
```

And I'd like to suggest that you should not play with DOM from angular controller, I think the directive would be best way to this what `isScrolledIntoView = function(elem) {...}` function is doing.

Comment: does $window.onscroll is getting called or not??

Comment: Yes, it works pretty well. Problem with something else.

Answer (score -1):

You can add an event listener in your JS file to listen for the position of that ID. In other words, you'll probably need to make a directive that is attached to the thing you want to display, and in that directive you want to have the position always sending. So, use jquery in a new directive, and have it ping it's position, then if the position of that is a y value that is on the monitor bingo.

In other words, if your monitor is 1000px high, and your element is 1400px below, you scroll 400px downward, jquery will recognize that your window scroll height has changed, then you can fire off a function.

Don't want to give you the code, but a high-level understanding. Does this help?

```
$("#scrollid").scroll(function(){
  // get current window height
//then get id position on page
// if window scroll overlaps with id position, set display:bock or whatever
})
```

Comment: If you make an example I will appreciate it! =) Thank you anyway in advance!

Comment: This should be made a directive, though. Just showing you the idea behind it so you can learn the concept then apply your angular knowledge to create a better directive.